# How to print full path to script files in @sql annotation in spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

In a multi-module project I want to be sure that Spring's @sql annotation uses correct resources. Is there a way to log full path of those files to console somehow?
Spring does log script file name before execution, but in tests for different modules those file names are the same sometimes.

Comment: You can convert resource to file and log path - `resource.getFile().getPath()`

Comment: Will this be equivalent? I don't use class loader.
`new File("src/test/resources").getAbsolutePath();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener` - responsible for the processing of `@Sql`, for the first step you can change to debug related log by adding property `logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.jdbc=debug`, but the debug message is not fully and if is not enough you should create your own `TestExecutionListener` and declare on test class `@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = SqlScriptsCustomTestExecutionListener.class)`
 for example:

```
public class SqlScriptsCustomTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) {
        List<Resource> scriptResources = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<Sql> sqlAnnotations = AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedRepeatableAnnotations(testContext.getTestMethod(), Sql.class);
        for (Sql sqlAnnotation : sqlAnnotations) {
            String[] scripts = sqlAnnotation.scripts();
            scripts = TestContextResourceUtils.convertToClasspathResourcePaths(testContext.getTestClass(), scripts);
            scriptResources.addAll(TestContextResourceUtils.convertToResourceList(testContext.getApplicationContext(), scripts));
        }
        if (!scriptResources.isEmpty()) {

            String debugString = scriptResources.stream().map(r -> {
                try {
                    return r.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to found file resource");
                }
                return null;
            }).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

            System.out.println(String.format("Execute sql script :[%s]", debugString));
        }
    }
```

It is just quick example and it works.   Most of source code i copied  from `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener` just for explanation. It is just realization in case of `@Sql` annotation on method level, and not included class level.
 I hope it will be helps you.