# How do I ensure my @Sql queries are shown in my console log?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, spring-test

Here's an MRE:

```java
package com.example.h2_demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;

@DataJpaTest
@Sql(
        executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
        scripts = {"/create_user_table.sql", "/insert_user.sql"}
)
public class H2DemoApplicationTest {
    @Test
    void testNothing() {
    }

    @Test
    void testNothingOneMoreTime() {
    }
}
```

```sql
-- create_user_table.sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

```sql
-- insert_user.sql

INSERT INTO users
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe');
```

I tinkered with the scripts a bit and now am fairly sure that the `@Sql` scripts *are* executed. However, it's not obvious when you look in the logs. No relevant `CREATE` or `INSERT` statements are present

I did try every property I saw suggested on the Internet (including on StackOverflow). At this point, my properties are:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace

logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.jdbc=debug
```

I double-checked and made sure that these values were present in the `application.properties` of the `target` folder

No logs still (sorry for the image, don't see a workaround)

[text search for "insert" provides no matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABjS3.png)

How do I see those `@Sql` queries in my logs?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805597/how-to-print-full-path-to-script-files-in-sql-annotation-in-spring-boot-test

Comment: Where are you storing your application.properties file It seems you're running a test env so what I would suggest is make a new resource folder inside your test and then make an application-test.properties and annotate @ActiveProfile to test that way you might abe to see the logs on console if it works let me know so that I can put complete Answer

Comment: @berse2212 It doesn't work with logging queries, not just script namess

Comment: @Daksharajkamal no, it doesn't. I still don't see the queries

Comment: @Kodigas I digged around in the SqlScriptsTestsExecutionListener and maybe this line might help:
`logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init=DEBUG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see which `@Sql` **scripts** are being executed, set the `org.springframework.test.context.jdbc` logging category to `DEBUG`.

If you want to see which SQL **statements** are being executed, set the `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init` logging category to `DEBUG`.

Note that I've also opened a [ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31589) to improve the documentation in Spring to reflect this.